# Pagina HTML no me muestra el css ni Imagenes

Tags: html, css

Tengo una pagina la cual estoy haciendo... pero al depurarla no me muestra ningun contenido css ni imagenes, solo la estructura HTML, tengo la carpeta en el escritorio como Prueba 2 y dentro de ella tengo /css, /html/, image2/, /Images, /js, cabe destacar que están separadas obviamente y no una dentro de otra. aquí un poco del codigo

```
<title>Diseño y Desarrollo Web</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo2.css">
```

```
<header>
    <h1><a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="images/logo.png">Tienda BoxChamps</a></h1>
    <ul>

        <li> <a href="inicio.html">Home</a></li>
        <li> <a href="acerca.html">Acerca</a></li>
        <li> <a href="productos.html">Productos</a></li>
        <li> <a class="actual" href="index.html">Ofertas</a></li>
        <li> <a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
        <li> <a href="formulario.html">Formulario</a></li>

    </ul>
</header>
<main>

    <section class="slider">
        <div class="slider__container container">
            <img src="assets/leftarrow.svg" class="slider__arrow" id="before">

            <section class="slider__body slider__body--show" data-id="1">
                <div class="slider__texts">
                    <h2 class="subtitle">
                    Guantes Boxeo Profesionales
                    </h2>
                    <p class="slider__review">
                        Guantes marca Everlast
                    </p>
                </div>
                <figure class="slider__picture">
                    <img src="image2/imagen1.jpg" class="slider__img">
                </figure>
            </section>
```

Agradezco su ayuda de antemano

Comment: ¿Y como es tu url?  Es decir, ¿algo así como `http://localhost/Prueba 2/html/index.html`?  Pon la ruta completa para saber desde donde estas abriendo ese html

Comment: **file:///C:/Users/javie/Desktop/Prueba%202/html/index.html** desconozco por que se le coloca un %20 debe ser por el espacio

Comment: Entonces el problema lo tienes en las rutas relativas que usas en tus llamadas a imagenes y demas... Al principio cuesta un poco de entender, pero tal como tienes tu estructura debes poner `../` en cada enlace que no te carga, porque así retrocedes un directorio (carpeta) y luego avanzas hasta el que toca, como este: `href="css/estilo2.css"` que debes cambiar por este:  `href="../css/estilo2.css"`.  Otra cosa seria que tu archivo `index.html` lo tuvieras una carpeta atras, entonces te funcionaria sin cambiar nada.

Comment: ¿Ya has revisado el log del navegador para ver si te da mensajes de error y cuáles?

Comment: Entiendo que tienes carpetas html, css y js por separado, entonces desde el índex debes ir una carpeta hacia atrás, para eso debes agregar ../ antes de la ruta en lugar que invoques a css o js, ya que las 3 carpetas están en un mismo nivel, entonces como el index está dentro de /html, debes ir una carpeta hacia atrás, luego entrar a css y ahí utilizar el archivo, lo mismo sucedería con js o con imágenes.

Answer (score 1):

si tu estructura de archivos es la siguiente:

Todas carpetas independientes:

```
/Prueba2
       /css
       /html
       /image2
       /Images
       /js
```

Cuando tu ingresas a un index.html estás parado dentro de la carpeta html, entonces para lograr llegar a otra carpeta primero debes ir un nivel hacia atrás, para eso se utilizan lo que se conoce como rutas relativas, en tu caso "../" antes de la ruta, lo que hace que vaya un nivel hacia atrás y luego busque la carpeta deseada. Dicho esto,  tu código debería quedar algo así para funcionar, ejemplo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilo2.css">
```

De todos modos aprovecho para mencionar que en general en la industria se utiliza como estructura base la siguiente:

```
/proyectoX
          /css/styles.css
          /js/app.js
          /img/imagen.jpg
          index.html
```

Donde sería /carpeta/archivo.extensión

Notar que las carpetas están al **mismo nivel** que index.html, por lo que para invocar css, js o imagenes, sería suficiente con lo siguiente:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo2.css">
```

En este caso no sería necesario el uso de rutas relativas.

Espero sirva para resolver tu inconveniente, quedo a las ordenes.